# Why do I need `fclose` after writing to a file in PHP?

Tags: php

Why do I need to finish by using the `fclose($handle)` function after writing to a file using php? Doesn't the program automatically do this when it ends?

Comment: Yes.  PHP automatically closes file handles at script termination.  In any sort of cicumstances where the script will not be immediately terminating following file IO, it's probably a good idea to close the file, however.  e.g., if you write a library, and that library is used by a CLI script that calls your library function hundreds of times, it had better close the file after each call.

Comment: @Frank, that should have been an answer so it could be upvoted. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. But, it's good practice to do it yourself. Also, you'll leave the file open during the entire exection of the remainder of the script, which you should avoid. So unless your script finishes execution directly after you're finished writing, you're basically leaving the file open longer than you need to.

Comment: Is that a bad thing to leave it open? What are the downsides to leaving it open?

Comment: You're using more memory, and other processes may not be able to use that file.

Comment: You need to back up your claim with a citation of the php.net manual or the source code of the interpreter.

Comment: There are also limits to how many open file handles the O/S allows, so if you're iterating through thousands of files, your PHP script will eventually (probably) crash if you're not closing the files when you're done with them.

Answer (score 12):

There may be unwritten data sitting in the output buffer that doesn't get written until the file is closed. If an error occurs on the final write, you can't tell that the output is incomplete which may cause all sorts of problems much later.

By explicitly calling `fclose()` *and* checking its return value, you have the opportunity to:

- Retry the operation
- Unroll the changes
- Return a failure condition to a calling function
- Report the problem to the user
- Document the problem in a log file
- Return a failure indication to execution environment (such as a command line shell) which may be crucial when used in a tool chain.

or some other way that fits your situation.

This is mention in the comments section of the [`fclose()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).

Answer (score 9):

There are also security implications to leaving file descriptors open: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/403.html

Your program might execute a program with different privilege levels, and a leaked file descriptor may allow private information to cross a boundary between processes of two different trust levels:

http://osvdb.org/7559
[CVE-2006-5397](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2006-5397)
[CVE-2007-5159](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2007-5159)
[CVE-2008-3914](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-3914)

The fun thing with security bugs is that it might be perfectly safe when you write the initial function, but a year or two later might become unsafe due to an innocent-looking change.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, PHP normally closes the file before exiting. But you should always close it manually:

1- It's a good programming practice

2- PHP can exit unexpectedly (for example, an uncaught exception). This may leave the file  with something in the queue to be written, or with a lock in it.

Comment: I would expect an uncaught exception to still clean up file handles.  However, I've certainly seen PHP segfault more than a few times, and there's no way PHP can do any sort of cleanup in that situation

Answer (score 0):

Except when the program doesn't end or takes long, it counts towards maximum open file handles in the system. But yes, PHP allows for laziness.

Answer (score 0):

Not only in PHP, in every language we should close the stream when work is done. In this way we are allowing others to use that file.
If we dont close it, other programs may not use it till the program ends completely (in this case page).

Answer (score -2):

When a file is opened, a lock is placed on it, preventing other processes from using it.  `fclose()` removes this lock.

`$handle` is not an object, just a pointer.  So there is no destructor telling it to unlock.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your pronouns here. When you say a lock is placed on it, do you mean a lock is placed on the file? If so, what does the lock have to do with using the function? What does the lock do?

Comment: the lock is placed on a file.  if you are writing to the file, and then another process comes along and tries to write the file - access will be denied because two different things can't write to a file at the same time.  the lock prevents the second process from being able to write.

Comment: so this is a reason why it doesn't matter right? As long as you have different names for your pointers, then you should have no problems writing multiple files in the same program.

Comment: No, any process writing to a file gets the lock so that a different process can not write to the file. If you open the file, it gets locked, if something else tries to write to that file that second write process has to wait until the file is released / unlocked - which is achieved with fclose. The sooner your close your file and release the lock, the sooner something else can write to that file again.

Comment: -1, factually incorrect.  PHP *does not* automatically place locks on files.  If you want or need locking, you must expressly request a lock during or immediately after the open.  Additionally, the latest point releases of PHP [now require that you expressly release the lock prior to close](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), while the lock would previously be released with `fclose` alone.