# What happens when we open a file in php and do not close it?

Tags: php, file, garbage-collection

Here goes some code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
# fclose($myfile);
?>
```

What will happen if I will not remove the comment in the third line?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038764/why-do-i-need-fclose-after-writing-to-a-file-in-php

Answer (score 3):

PHP auto-closes files at the end of a document or before `exit()`ing.

PHP will also dump the memory once the last reference to the file is parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collector will free the resource when no more reference is detected anymore.

Quoting from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) :

> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend
>   Engine, a resource with no more references to it is detected
>   automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector. For this
>   reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.
>
> Note: Persistent database links are an exception to this rule. They
>   are not destroyed by the garbage collector. See the persistent
>   connections section for more information.

Garbage collection working process of PHP can be described in short like this :

- A zval container is created when a new variable is created with a constant value
- GC keep tracks of the number of reference of this container.
- When no one is referencing this container GC add this to another container known as `root buffer`.
- GC runs whenever the `root buffer` turns full.
- You can use [gc_collect_cycles(](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)) function to force GC to run.

To know more about how PHP GC please consult with [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php).

Answer (score 1):

Once the process is done, the operating system will release all its resources - allocated memory and file descriptors. So nothing much will happen, unless of course the code goes on - the number of file descriptors per process is limited and it's generally good style to release them as soon as you're done with them.