Laravel LazyCollection: why is there no flow closing?
The Laravel documentation has a LazyCollection::make() example at Lazy Collection documentation
LazyCollection::make(function () {
    $handle = fopen('log.txt', 'r');
 
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        yield $line;
    }
});

So I'm wondering why there's no fclose() call.
In my code I'm using the gzopen() and it seems very strange to me to not call gzclose().
Thanks
I've Google and found nothing so I asked my coworkers; nobody knows, so one of them asked Chat-GPT and we can't get any reliable answer.

Why don't you ask the folks at Laravel who maintain that documentation? Maybe that's a bug, and if not, they can tell you best why they didn't put it into the example code

It might not be as important to do so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038764/why-do-i-need-fclose-after-writing-to-a-file-in-php

I think you can add fclose($handle) after the while loop without causing weird behavior.

@IGP: I think so but I'm a little bit confused with Laravel's syntax so I'd like to be sure I don't miss something.

@NicoHaase: simply because I thought it could be PHP related and SOF has a better audience so I could have better answers wich will be profitable to more people
